# Display every hour another content

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to show different content on my site every hour, I found this:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eBAGS/5/):

```
<button onClick="getPhrase()">Show me a phrase for this hour</button>
<div id="placeHolder"></div>
```

```
window.getPhrase = function() {
    h = new Date().getHours(); //Get the current hour

    phrase = new Array(); //Create an array of phrases
    phrase[1] = 'Hello';
    phrase[2] = 'there';
    phrase[3] = 'this';
    phrase[4] = 'will';
    phrase[5] = 'show';
    phrase[6] = 'a';
    phrase[7] = 'different';
    phrase[8] = 'message';
    phrase[9] = 'depending';
    phrase[10] = 'on';
    phrase[11] = 'the';
    phrase[12] = 'hour';
    phrase[13] = 'of';
    phrase[14] = 'day';
    phrase[15] = 'that';
    phrase[16] = 'you';
    phrase[17] = 'look';
    phrase[18] = 'at';
    phrase[19] = 'it';
    phrase[20] = '!';
    phrase[21] = 'W';
    phrase[22] = 'X';
    phrase[23] = 'Y';
    phrase[24] = 'Z';

    document.getElementById('placeHolder').innerHTML = phrase[h-1]; //Show the array item relevant to the hour
}
```

But how can I display this without a button?
How can I remove the button?

Comment: ...don't use a button?

Comment: try using `setInterval` function.

Comment: When I remove <button onClick="getPhrase()">Show me a phrase for this hour</button> this, it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Please use an array literal: `phrase = ['Hello', 'there', 'this', 'will', 'show', 'a', 'different', 'message', 'depending', 'on', 'the', 'hour', 'of', 'day', 'that', 'you', 'look', 'at', 'it', '!', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'];` Much shorter than that array declaration there.

Answer (score 0):

With a timer. This will refresh the phrase every second.

```
setInterval(function() {
    h = new Date().getHours(); //Get the current hour

    phrase = new Array(); //Create an array of phrases
    phrase[1] = 'Hello';
    phrase[2] = 'there';
    phrase[3] = 'this';
    phrase[4] = 'will';
    phrase[5] = 'show';
    phrase[6] = 'a';
    phrase[7] = 'different';
    phrase[8] = 'message';
    phrase[9] = 'depending';
    phrase[10] = 'on';
    phrase[11] = 'the';
    phrase[12] = 'hour';
    phrase[13] = 'of';
    phrase[14] = 'day';
    phrase[15] = 'that';
    phrase[16] = 'you';
    phrase[17] = 'look';
    phrase[18] = 'at';
    phrase[19] = 'it';
    phrase[20] = '!';
    phrase[21] = 'W';
    phrase[22] = 'X';
    phrase[23] = 'Y';
    phrase[24] = 'Z';

    document.getElementById('placeHolder').innerHTML = phrase[h-1]; //Show the array item relevant to the hour
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be overkill to run that function every second?
Also, I'd suggest adding some info about array literal notation: `phrase = ['Hello', 'there', 'this', 'will', ...... 'X', 'Y', 'Z'];        `.

Comment: It depends on the precision with which you want the switch from one phrase to the next to occur. Once every second is not that much.

Answer (score 0):

this will call after every hour
**javascript**

```
function getPhrase(){
    var h = new Date().getHours(); //Get the current hour
    var phrase = new Array(); //Create an array of phrases
    phrase = ['Hello', 'there', 'this', 'will', 'show', 'a', 'different', 'message', 'depending', 'on', 'the', 'hour', 'of', 'day', 'that', 'you', 'look', 'at', 'it', '!', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'];
    document.getElementById('placeHolder').innerHTML = phrase[h-1]; //Show the array item relevant to the hour
}
```

---

```
setInterval(getPhrase,60*60*1000);
```

remove the button

**html**

```
<div id="placeHolder"></div>
```